# Dynamic extensions to errors object in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

`React-hook-form` provides an errors object through useForm. Since checking for error  is dependent on the name attribute of the input field (something like `{errors.title?.type === "require" && <p>Title required</p>}`) and I create the input field names dynamically , I need to somehow set the extension dynamically too.
`{errors.title?.type === "require" && <p>Title required</p>}` is created together with the form fields. Each new form field has one to validate it.

Because `errors.title` could be `errors.title_3`, so:

```
{errors.
```

> title   <--This part would need to be dynamic, maybe dependant on props or state etc.

```
?.type === "require" && <p>Title required</p>}
```

I tried really hard to solve this propblem. I tried different variations of using `eval()` to get a string to function as logic. It created the logic dynamically but it didn't rerender when a form field error occured to display the error. So `<p>Title required</p>` was created. Don't know why.
I also tried to make it work trough useState and useEffect but I couldn't. I searched the web for solutions but didn't find any.

The solutions might be through react-hook-form, React or the solution might just be based in javascript. I really don't know. I'm just confused after hours of trying.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try errors[dynamic].type. Also think about test if  errors[dynamic] != undefined.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. When I try errors[dynamic]?.type it doesn't render. When I try errors[dynamic].message it returns an error says TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined.

Comment: Don't put the "?" and yes, this is because you don't have errors yet, so you have to check if errors[title] exists with errors[title] != undefined && errors[title].message

Comment: errors.title.message is the same as errors['title'].message.

Comment: I tried it just now. The error doesn't occur however it still doesn't display the error message. Does it not reevaluate that logic when it rerenders? It works fine with preset form field names and preset error names.

Comment: Depend how you're storing errors in your state. But generaly errors aren't set until you have errors so errors = empty array until there.

Comment: Give your code, so I can check for you and explain

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and I was able to resolve it using the [Error Message component](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformstate/errormessage).

Below is a code snippet:

```js
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
    
<ErrorMessage
  errors={errors}
  name={dynamicNameGoesHere}
/>
```

I hope this helps someone.